# Why is it more expensive to declare storage variables in a proxy?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, gas, storage

I want to deploy many contracts with the same functionality, so I decided to use delegatecalls. I have my contract `ActualContract` that contains all the functionality and a contract `ProxyContract` that contains only this delegation logic:

```
import "./ActualContract.sol";

contract ProxyContract {
    ActualContract immutable actualContract;
    
    
    constructor(ActualContract _actualContract) {
        actualContract = _actualContract;
    }
    
    // Make sure that the proxy contract may receive eth.
    receive() external payable {
    }
    
    fallback(bytes calldata _input) external payable returns (bytes memory) {
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = address(actualContract).delegatecall(_input);
        if (!success) { revert(getRevertMessage(data)); }
        return data;
    }
    
    // The deployment gas costs can almost be halved by removing the revert message code
    // but revert messages are useful for debugging.
    function getRevertMessage(bytes memory _returnData) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        if (_returnData.length < 68) {
            return "silent revert";
        }
        assembly {
            _returnData := add(_returnData, 0x04)
        }
        return abi.decode(_returnData, (string));
    }
}
```

If I want to have the proxy itself contain storage variables that are not visible to `ActualContract`, I think I need to declare all the storage variables `ActualyContract`. However, this is very expensive.

I do understand that the deployment of the proxy contract may be more expensive if I declared variables in the proxy contract (even though they are not given values are and not read, so could be optimized away) because maybe storage space still gets allocated for them. However, `ActualContract` contains an `initialize()` function that writes a value to each storage variable. I'd imagine that gas paid for allocation of the variables does not need to be paid again, so the sum of the deployment and the initialization (call of `initialize()` using the fallback function of `ProxyContract`) should come out at the same cost regardless of whether I declared variables in the proxy. As I'm writing this question, you know that that's not the case and I want to know why.

I measured the gas costs on Ganache CLI v6.12.2 (ganache-core: 2.13.2) and used solc 0.8.7 with optimization at 200 runs. These are the gas costs I got (proxy deployment cost + initialization cost):

```
No storage variables in the proxy contract:    196'910 + 264'866 = 461'776
With storage variables in the proxy contract:  305'740 + 305'740 = 611'480
```

As you can see, these costs are far from equal. Why is this?

For the measurement, I only declared storage variables that are written to in `initialize()` in `ProxyContract`. These are 1 address, 1 bool, and 10 uint256s.